# Given a finite alphabet, how to generate all possible strings while excluding those that don't feature an element at least once?

Tags: strings, enumeration

Say you have the finite alphabet {*a*,*b*,*c*,*d*,*e*,*f*,*g*}. It's trivial to enumerate all strings of length <= 1000 over that set.

But what would be an efficient way of specifying a subset of those strings that include "*e*" at least once?

The obvious and least efficient way is to enumerate all strings and discard the ones that don't feature the desired element, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every position $0\le i\le 1000$, enumerate over all strings that have $e$ at their $i$'th spot. This can be easily done as you need to enumerate on strings with length $i-1$ and strings with length $n-i$, and concatenate them together with an $e$ between them. This can even be done in-place if you want to